# Getting two outputs instead of one in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date

The question here was to find if the date provided is a valid one or not without using native Matlab date functions. I was hoping if someone can point out my mistake here. I'm also getting the "Output argument `valid` (and maybe others) not assigned during call to `valid_date`" error in Matlab learning tool when I submit it.

```
function valid = valid_date(year,month,day)

if nargin~=3
    valid = false;
elseif ~isscalar(year)||year<1||year~=fix(year)
    valid = false;
    return
elseif ~isscalar(month)||month<1||month~=fix(month)
    valid = false;
    return
elseif ~isscalar(day)||day<1||day~=fix(day)
    valid = false;
    return
elseif month>12 || day > 31
    valid = false;
end

if ((mod(year,4)==0 && mod(year,100)~=0) || mod(year,400)==0)
    leapdata=1;
else
    leapdata=0;
end

%the below if statements are used to define the months. Some months have 
%31 days and others have 30 days, while February has only 28 days and 29 on
%leap years. this is checked in the below code.
% I feel the below code is where the error is.

if ismember (month, [1 3 5 7 8 10 12])
    ismember (day, (1:31))
    return
elseif ismember( month, [4 6 9 11])
    ismember (day, (1:30))
    return
end


if month == 2
    if leapdata==1
        ismember (day, (1:29))
        return
    elseif leapdata==0
        ismember (day, (1:28))
        return
    else
        valid = false;
    end 
end
```

Comment: Please start with the basics: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html — learning to program by trial and error is unnecessary frustrating, and skipping learning the basics will lead you down a painful road.

Comment: You sre forgetting to assign `valid` value in multiples returns. Also, I would suggest you to post the entire error to see more clear where the error happens

Comment: @CrisLuengo, this is actually a question from a basics level course. True, it's super frustrating to do it by trial and error, I was stuck on this for almost 9 hours on Saturday :/

Answer (score 0):

When returning at the end of a Matlab function, the value of the variable `valid` is sent as an output. In the lines below the four comments, you need to assign the variable to true or false inside of the if statements. For example:

```matlab
if ismember(month, [1 3 5 7 8 10 12])
    valid = ismember(day, (1:31))
    return
elseif ismember(month, [4 6 9 11])
    valid = ismember(day, (1:30))
    return
end


if month == 2
    if leapdata == 1
        valid = ismember(day, (1:29))
        return
    elseif leapdata == 0
        valid = ismember(day, (1:28))
        return
    else
        valid = false;
    end 
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, I'm still getting a double output :(

Comment: @BungyCord You need to understand the difference between the output of a function and stuff written to the console by the function. Check for lines not having a semicolon at the end (hint: there are 4 in the bit of code in this answer). Do use the MATLAB Editor, and do pay attention to the warnings it gives you. It does warn on these lines with missing semicolon.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, oh, damn, my bad. Missed to check the editor. The double outputs have stopped, but getting the wrong results. Nonetheless, I'm confident I'll be able to find the error. Thanks a ton :D